# Matrix with List<List <string > > Indexof

Tags: c#, list

I need to simulate a Matrix of data and Im using a `List<List <string >>`.
Im using the `IndexOf` to search an element in a list of the list.

```
Matrix[0].IndexOf('Search');
```

But is it possible to make a kind of `IndexOf` in `Matrix`?

Comment: indexOf traditionally returns a single number. Such a function will not make sense over a two dimensional matrix. Let us say you want a Position of which returns the index of the list and then the index of the string within the list, you could write your own extension method which loops through lists and then does and index of to give you the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx) method:

```
int index = Matrix.FindIndex(x => x[colIndex] == "Search");
```

This method is obviously useful if you want to search the row index by knowing the column to search in.

If you want to search in the whole matrix you could write a simple method:

```
public static Tuple<int,int> PositionOf<T>(this List<List<T>> matrix, T toSearch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
    {
        int colIndex = matrix[i].IndexOf(toSearch);
        if (colIndex >= 0 && colIndex < matrix[i].Count)
            return Tuple.Create(i, colIndex);
    }
    return Tuple.Create(-1, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make your own class to achieve it.

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    public void IndexOf<T>(T value, out int x, out int y){...}
}
```

or use an extension on your type

```
public static void IndexOf<T>(this List<List<T>> list, out int x, out int y){...}
```

Personally, I'd make the extension on a 2 dimensional array rather than `List<List<T>>`.

Comment: Well, you _could_ just make a helper/extension method rather than a whole class.

Comment: @Rawling was typing out the syntax as you were making the comment

Comment: Could return Tuple<int,int> instead of using out params.

Comment: @juharr I could have also used dynamic, but I like this strong typing better.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i<Matrix.Length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<Matrix.Length; j++)
        if(Matrix[i][j] == "Search")
        {
            //OUT i,j;
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *may be* are asking for something like :

*Example*

```
public void MatrixIndexOf(string content) {
      var result = matrix.Select((value, index)=> new {
        _i = index,
       _str = value
      }).Where(x=>x._str.Contains(content));
}
```

after this `result` is anonymous type where`_i` is index.